# React-Select Multi Searchable: NOT allowing me to search by separated letters or word snippets

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, react-select, react-dom

### ISSUE

Hello Guys please help me to solve this. I've started building a REACT application working with some JSON data, and now I got stuck on this problem when trying to tap **some letters** or **word snippets** to search on options from the select that could contain that letter or those snippet(s).

Check the example and my code below please, I have only one list stored in a **react-select** component, I'm using react v15.6.2, react-dom v15.6.2 and react-select 2.1.0. Thanks in advance.

> Example: If I tap letter 'a', the search works fine and it gives me the options that contain that letter but when I add something else that is NOT exactly before/after the letter 'a', example: I add a letter 'b' that can be at the last of the option value, the select stops giving results!

```
const selectObjects = (<Select
  isMulti
  options={this.state.list.map(obj => {
    return {
      value: obj.id,
      label: obj.id + ' ' + obj.name
    };
  })}
  onChange={this.handleChangeObj}
  value={this.state.list}
/>);
```

**[PRESS HERE TO CHECK THE DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaZad.gif)**

Comment: Can you show us some code? If you're using custom filter function it might be the issue (the default searches anywhere in the label). Also you might want to use the `getOptionValue` and `getOptionLabel` props to map your value/label, rather than doing so directly in the `options`.

Comment: Thanks @Steve-Cutter-Blades, but I'm not using any custom filter function yet, neither the `getOptionValue` or `getOptionLabel` how to work with those things could you help me ? thanks in advance?

Comment: `getOptionValue={(opt) => opt.id}` and `getOptionLabel={(opt) => opt.id + ' ' + opt.name}`

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that, if you map your option label and value correctly, your search issue should be resolved.

```
const options = [{
  id: 2,
  artist: 'Hendrix, Jimi',
  title: 'Red House'
}, {
  id: 3,
  artist: 'Clapton, Eric',
  title: `I'm Tore Down`
}];

<Select options={options}
        getOptionValue={(opt) => opt.id}
        getOptionLabel={(opt) => `${opt.artist}: ${opt.title}`} />
```

I have a [larger example in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zx45kql9q4).

Comment: Hi again, I realized that you have same problem as me! I went into the link that you gave here and tried your Select and I got same result as mine, when I search for the word 'fantasy' with letter 'f' for example, and then I add somthing related to some next words the select stop giving results! Also, there is no filter function in your code.

Comment: yes, the search functionality looks for concurrent characters (i.e. `e cr` would return the option `Ice Cream`). Anything more advanced would require a custom filter function, which you can do passing a `filterOption` prop.

Comment: no my friend your select is not solving my issue, it doesn't work with snippets, you can see if you want on codesandbox.

Comment: You will have to tell me exactly what you are trying to type in that you find isn't working, and what result is it that you were expecting, because in my codesandbox (from above), it is doing exactly what I thought it should do. For instance, if I type `s th` it filters down to `Fantasy: Dreams That Money Can Buy`, as expected.

Comment: yes because that expression "s th" index is the 15th one, found in the option and its not considered as 2 separated snippets. All what I want to do is to make a search by some separated keywords in the option, for example if I have an option with this value: "Fanatasy dream 08", if I tap 'F' then 'Dream', which will be shown as "fdream" gives the me result of "Fanatasy dream 08". I want the search detect the letters from all the words from all indexs in the select! thats all

Comment: Then yes, that is not how the default filtering works, and you would need to write a custom filtering method that you apply with the `filterOption` prop, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Could you provide me with examples of how to create such custom method please?

Comment: I can't give you an example that would meet your needs, but they do provide an example of how to setup custom filters in the documentation, as the second example on this page https://react-select.com/advanced

Comment: I've already entered on that link and didn't find any example that match my need, that's why I'm sharing my issue here!

Comment: Ahhh, Ok. I've updated my codesandbox to use a custom `filterOption`. It is very basic, checking to see if an option begins with the `inputValue` put in. Two things to note from my example. One, it's case sensitive (no flags on the RegExp). Two, it tests the `option.label`, which I overrode with my `getOptionLabel` property.

Comment: So, using the example as a template for 'how' to write your own custom filter, you can now write your own option matching logic to filter your option set. The filter is run against each option in your `options` array, and will only show those for which your filter returns `true`.